# Ajax form submit alert

Tags: ajax

I'm having a problem while submitting a form through AJAX.When I'm clicking submit button the form is submitted successfully but not getting alert.Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function () {
$('#register').on('submit',function (e) {

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '',
            data: $('#register').serialize(),
            success: function () {
            alert("Information Submitted");
            }
          });
      e.preventDefault();
    });});
```

Please tell where I'm wrong?

Comment: if you don't give URL it will go to error or complete block  , please use error:function(){}, complete:function(){} keep your alert in these

Comment: I'm giving url I removed it before posting this script here

Comment: then use the above mentioned blocks and check if you still facing the problem

Comment: What if you replace `e.preventDefault();` by `return false;`?

Comment: Sorry then also not giving alert

Comment: what if there is error in ajax request?? check console.